# Question about measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have been thinking about the problem stated below for some time but still get the least intuition of how to solve it. Any hint or comment from you will be greatly appreciated!

[Problem]

Let $\mu,\nu$ be two probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, and $\lambda$ a positive measure which dominates both $\mu$ and $\nu$(This means $\mu,\nu$ are both absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$). Show that
$$\sup_{A\in\mathcal{F}}|\mu(A)-\nu(A)|={1 \over 2}\int_\Omega\bigg|{d\mu \over d\lambda}-{d\nu \over d\lambda}\bigg|\ d\lambda$$

I tried to use Radon-Nikodym's theorem and decompose $\mu$ with respect to $\nu$ in terms of Lebesgue's Decomposition but it does not seem to work so much. Neither did I really get how ${1 \over 2}$ came.

Comment: Dear @Roy Han: I removed the deprecated tag 'analysis'. Please feel free to add a more specific tag to replace it.

Comment: The 1/2 comes because the integral on the right hand side, if performed without the absolute value sign, equals 0, since both $\mu,\lambda$ are probability. Can you do the version of the problem where $\Omega = [0,1]$, $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure, and $d\mu/d\lambda$ and $d\nu/d\lambda$ are non-negative integrable functions? Lastly, this question is not research level, and so I am voting to migrate to MSE.

Comment: To Wong: Thank you very much for your advice. I have solved the problem very quickly as I posted it so I felt terribly sorry to have troubled you. It is definitely not research-level problem as you have said, but I am not sure what you are referring to as "MSE"?

Comment: Sorry to have forgotten @WillieWong

Answer (score 1):

Let's write $d\mu=f\,d\lambda$ and $d\nu =g\,d\lambda$ (opinions vary regarding the desirability of letter $d$ in such formulas). Observe that 
$$
0=\int_\Omega (f-g)\,d\lambda = \int_{\Omega^+}(f-g)\,d\lambda+\int_{\Omega^-}(f-g)\,d\lambda
\tag1$$
where I use the notation  $\Omega^+=\{x:f(x)-g(x)>0\}$ and  $\Omega^-=\{x:f(x)-g(x)<0\}$. 
This implies 
$$
\int_{\Omega^+}(f-g)\,d\lambda=-\int_{\Omega^-}(f-g)\,d\lambda=\frac12 \int_{\Omega}|f-g|\,d\lambda
\tag2$$
For any measurable set $A$ we have 
$$
\mu(A)-\nu(A)=\int_A (f-g)\,d\lambda = \int_{A\cap \Omega^+} (f-g)\,d\lambda + \int_{A\cap \Omega^-} (f-g)\,d\lambda \le \int_{\Omega^+} (f-g)\,d\lambda +0 
$$
The equality holds when $A=\Omega^+$. Thus, 
$$\sup_A\,(\mu(A)-\nu(A))=  \frac12 \int_{\Omega}|f-g|\,d\lambda \tag3$$
The roles of $\mu$ and $\nu$ can be reversed in (3): 
$$\sup_A\,(\nu(A)-\mu(A))=\frac12 \int_{\Omega}|f-g|\,d\lambda$$
and the conclusion follows.